# OpenCv, Python3: No icons in the toolbar

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am using Python 3.5 on Linux along with OpenCV 3.4.0 (installed by `pip install opencv-python`) to display the images from my webcam
and I want to use the toolbar at the top of my frame. But the icons of this toolbar aren't shown. (I could use the Buttons without the icons, but where are the Icons)

Is there any way to get the usual icons or write Text instead of icons on these buttons.
Here is my code:

```
import cv2
cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")



def show_webcam():
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cv2.namedWindow("webcam", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL|cv2.WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED)
    cv2.resizeWindow('webcam', 800, 800)

    while True:
       ret_val, img1 = cam.read()
       cv2.imshow('webcam', img1)
       if cv2.waitKey(100)  == 27: # wait for Esc
           break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

show_webcam()
```

Comment: Attach a screenshot. What platform? Where did the build of OpenCV come from?

Comment: I am an linux user and have installed OpenCV with: pip install opencv-python.

Comment: I have run the python script with Pycharm  and my Linux-Basch.

Comment: AFAIK, the expanded GUI is only available when using Qt GUI backend. You can check the details about how your copy of OpenCV was built using the [`getBuildInformation()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga0ae377100bc03ce22322926bba7fdbb5) function. However, you say there are no icons -- can you post a screenshot of that? CTRL+G allows you to insert images when you [edit] your post.