# cv2.imshow() not displaying text properly

Tags: python, opencv, xming

I am trying to display an image with cv2 in python:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('Prova.jpg')
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

the image looks good.
But all the texts are not showing correctly:

1. RGB values in the status bar are squares
2. icons in tool bar are blank
3. right-click menu text are squares

See:

### blank menu bar

[image]

and

### right-click menu

[image]

Specs:

- Anaconda with python 3.5
- SSH connection to server: Putty + Xming
- opencv 3.4.2

Anybody could please help?

Edit:

a normal output would be something like this:
[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't create any text! Please show the actual code to match your question.

Comment: The method does not require user to explicitly create any text, it shows information in status bar and menu bar with built-in functions. I have edited the question, please see an example of normal output window.

Comment: Are you sure this is normal output? That's how it is for me, i.e., tooltips and context menu do work, but the menu bar with the unlabaled buttons which can be clicked and do work is completely counter-intuitive for a first-time user. I think they should have text or icons. I'm using it without any SSH locally on Ubuntu 18.04. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095446/python-opencv-remove-title-bar-toolbar-and-status-bar) it has icons.

Comment: [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634045/opencv-python3-no-icons-in-the-toolbar) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55052759/2191065) [also](https://answers.opencv.org/question/214581/opencv-imshow-not-showing-icons/) [have](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/213) the problem with the missing icons. I'm using the opencv-python pip package.