# No button icons on OpenCV4 Named Windows and WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED

Tags: python, qt, opencv

I have the same problem as [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49634045/4483946)

When I use a named window in OpenCV 4 with WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED, I get the window with buttons (zoom in, zoom out, etc.), functionality OK, but no icon in those buttons, as you can see in the following capture:

[image]

I'm running Linux Mint 19.1, Python 3.6, OpenCV4 (pip3 install opencv-python) and the following Build Information from OpenCV:

```html
General configuration for OpenCV 4.0.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.0.0

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /io/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     4.0.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2019-01-09T18:07:09Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64
    CMake:                       3.9.0
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (5 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (11 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/c++  (ver 4.8.2)
    C++ flags (Release):         -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/cc
    C flags (Release):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib   
    Linker flags (Debug):        -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib   
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          ade /opt/Qt4.8.7/lib/libQtGui.so /opt/Qt4.8.7/lib/libQtTest.so /opt/Qt4.8.7/lib/libQtCore.so /lib64/libz.so /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib64/libjpeg.a avcodec avformat avutil swscale dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf quirc

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf java js matlab ovis python2 sfm ts viz
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          YES (ver 4.8.7 EDITION = OpenSource)
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.3)
    JPEG:                        /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib64/libjpeg.a (ver 62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.35)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 58.21.104)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 58.17.101)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 56.18.102)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 5.2.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /io/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/bin/python (ver 3.6.5)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.6m.a (ver 3.6.5)
    numpy:                       /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.3)
    packages path:               lib/python3.6/site-packages

  Python (for build):            /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/bin/python

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Best Regards!

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and OpenCV 3.4.4. I have the same issue. Have you found a solution?